# Mongo. Narroving down results of nested array

Tags: mongodb

If I have a document like this:

```
{
"name" : "Foo",
"words" : 
    [
      "lorem", 
      "ipsum",
      "dolor",
      "sit",
      "amet",
        ...
    ]
 }
```

Let's say this `words` array is pretty big. Now I need a query that would fetch that document:

`db.docs.find({'name':'Foo'})` - that will get whole document

but what I want, instead of fetching the entire `words` array (cause it's too big) I would like to retrieve only elements that meet some criteria. Let's say I want to see only words that start with "a" or have a length of at least 3 characters.
You know maybe something like this:

```
// this won't work! 
db.docs.find({
  "$where":"(this.words.map(function(e){ if (e.length >=3) { return e } }))" 
})
```

Comment: This question is a bit open ended. Specifically what is it you want to do?

Comment: I want to query a document, but limit the resulting data of `words`. I know how to say "hey mongo, give me all documents where length of array `words` is bigger than zero", but I don't know how to say "hey mongo, give me a specific document, but limit the `words` array and return only the elements of that array that meet specific criteria"

Comment: From where I am standing you asked a question "badly" 14 hours ago and it has not been answered  because you have not asked a reasonable question. So don't be so smug. What do you want to do? One question only. Lorem ipsum hypothetical examples do not get you real answers. Please ask a real question.

Comment: ok. let me try again: `db.docs.find({$where: '(this.words.length > 0)'})` - that will get all documents that have at least one element in `words` array. I know how to handle that on the document level. But how do I get down the next level? How can I do: `db.docs.find({'name':'Foo'}).filter({'words':$where'(this.length > 3)'})`. Of course that won't work but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

You cannot filter array contents using find, You can only match that the array contains the condition. So in order to filter the contents of the array you need to make use of aggregate:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
   // Still makes sense to match the documents that meet the condition
   { "$match": { 
       "name": "Foo", 
       "words": { "$regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,}" } 
   }},

   // Unwind the array to "de-normalize"
   { "$unwind": "$words" },

   // Actually "filter" the array elements
   { "$match": { "words": { "$regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,}" } } },

   // Group back the document with the "filtered" array
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "name": { "$first": "$name" },
       "words": { "$push": "$words" }
   }}
])
```

That makes use a regular expression condition that will match at least 4 characters from the start of the string. The `^` anchor is quite important here as it allows an index to be used which is much more optimal than whatever else you can do.

The result returned will look like this:

```js
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5341f0476cbcc02b995092ac"),
                    "name" : "Foo",
                    "words" : [
                            "lorem",
                            "ipsum",
                            "dolor"
                    ]
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can also throw a lot of arbitrary JavaScript at mapReduce and test the length of elements in the array, but that will take considerably longer to execute.

--

The terms are quite simple, you simply add the additional operator to the query document as so:

```js
db.docs.find({ "name": "Foo", "$where": "(this.words.length > 3)" })
```

You really should not be using the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator unless absolutely necessary, and even then you really should think about what you are doing. Heed the warnings that are given in that document.

As stated in the manual page for [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/), probably the best way to deal with detecting array length for a given range (rather than exact) is to create a "counter" field in your document that is updated as elements are added/removed from the array. This makes a very simple and efficient query:

```js
db.docs.find({ "name": "Foo", "counter": { "$gt": 3 } })
```

Of course from MongoDB versions 2.6 and upwards you can also do this:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "words": 1,
        "count": { "$size": "$words" }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "count": { "$gt": 3 }
    }}
])
```

Either of those forms is going to perform a lot better than using something that is going to remove the use of an index and then invoke the JavaScript interpreter over each resulting document. Or even just use the **`$size`** operator for an exact size of the array.

Comment: again, I understand `$where` thing, but want I need, is something like this: `db.docs.find({"$where":"(this.words.map(function(e){ return e.length > 3 }))"})`. But of course that won't work.

Comment: It's must be my English, as a non-native speaker I'm struggling to explain. Sorry. :(

Comment: I don't need to get documents that have 4 or more elements in `words` array (which is exactly what the first line of code in your answer does) I need to return only array elements (words) that 4 or more characters long and only those documents that contain arrays, that have elements of 4 or more characters long

Comment: @Agzam See how much clearer you last comment was than the actual question or use of imagined pseudo-code in other comments. That is how you should ask questions. There is a way to do this which I have updated the answer with.

Comment: Thank you Neil. This is very definitive answer. I learned a few new things.